# Feature selection methods for hybrid input data type (categorical and numerical) and numerical output

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection

I have a dataset about medical product manufacturing. The Products have 12 features(combination of categorical and numerical values) and a target(numerical) that indicates the amount of production. Now between different feature selection methods,  I want to know which one is more suitable to fit my data in Python?
thank you

Comment: Have you tried correlation heatmap to detect which ones are most significant?
About categories, you can transform them in a binary value (ex: Device category : {PC, TV or tablet} would become Is_PC:{0,1}, Is_TV:{0,1}, Is_Tablet:{0,1}

Comment: Thank you Nicolas.

Comment: You're welcome Majid. Could you push the up button to mark the comment as "useful" please?